# Cannot use Steam after upgrade Trusty 14.04.1 to the 14.04.2 HWE

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, lts, hardware-enablement-stack

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gnome-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3)
                    Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (>= 7.2)
unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages
```

Answer (score 1):

It`s a bug already reported in launchpad https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1424263

Some people are having luck with these packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're now using the HWE mesa stack then you are trying to install the wrong package.

With trusty -proposed still enabled - 
`sudo apt-get -s install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386`

If the simulation looks good then rerun the command but remove the `-s`

Comment: Nope 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 (= 10.3.2-0ubuntu1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed

Answer (score 0):

When installing the HWE if you combine the apt-get command from the official [Ubuntu HWE site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) with the fix from  [Launchpad Bug #1424263](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1424263) you can install the HWE safely (i.e without risking it de-installing Skype, Steam, WINE or any other 32-bit apps). The combined command is:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

*Note that Steam will still pop-up a little terminal window on launch and try to install some 32-bit mesa packages (since Steam isn't clever enough to know to look for the Utopic mesa packages you've installed with the above command). But this is a minor annoyance since all you need to do is ctrl+c or close the terminal window and Steam loads and runs fine.*